# QGIS Desktop 3.10.6 works fine when I use my laptop at the office but stops responding when using it at home

Tags: qgis, performance

I'm stumped on why my QGIS performance is terrible when working from home but fine in the office.

I am not using a vpn, all the files being used are on local hard drive, internet works fine at home, but despite this QGIS stops responding on start up and when ever I click a button or move the screen (not exaggerating, literally just clicking the identify features or pan button makes QGIS stop responding for 2-3mins).

I have no issues like this with other GIS software when working at home. When I used QGIS in the office on the same computer there are no issues.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What your PC's specs (work vs home)?

Comment: Using exactly the same data?

Comment: Same PC, same data. I tried creating a new QGIS project but even loading a blank map with no data and clicking buttons causes it to stop responding

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling QGIS? Maybe try updating to 3.16 while you're at it, you never know.

Comment: What happens if you disconnect the computer from wifi and run QGIS at home and in the office?

Comment: This really sounds like QGIS is trying to find a file that it can't locate. When it is opening a project, at the bottom it will say the layer it is currently attempting to load. See if it is hanging on a particular layer.
Also, try using a VPN -- maybe your local internet provider is blocking some resource QGIS is attempting to connect to.

Comment: Routers, firewalls, and antivirus programs are frequent culprits when this sort of thing happens. If it's a work computer, perhaps your IT set it to block certain ports when you're not on their network.

Comment: @GBG just tried turning off wifi and it opens fine. David Galt it happens just opening a blank map as well so it's not the file not being found but you might be right on something IT has set up. Will discuss with IT but for now I am just disconnecting from wifi when I need QGIS. Thanks